# SQL VS front end processing

Tags: c#, sql, performance

Recently I was working on a project in which JSON was used, I had two approaches to get data from database to facilitate my JavaScript with Json string,

**First**

Is to do processing in database to form a Json string, like this

```
select   
       ID,
    '{ "Comments": ['+
    Substring(
        (SELECT 
           ',{ '+
           '"Comment" : "' + REPLACE(Comments,'"','\"') + '",'+
           '"Name" : "' + REPLACE(Name,'"','\"') +
         '}'
    FROM    JsonTbl
    where   JsonTbl.ID = tbl.ID
    for xml path('')
    ),2,250000)
      +'] }' as JsonData
from tbl
```

**Second**

Is to select data from database without any processing and do processing of creating a Json string in front end, like this

```
DataTable data = GetDataFromDatabase();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("{ \"Comments\": [");
for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append("{");
    sb.Append("\"Comment\" : \"" + data.Rows[i]["Comment"].ToString().Replace('"', '\"') + "\",");
    sb.Append("\"Name\" : \"" + data.Rows[i]["Comment"].ToString().Replace('"', '\"') + "\"");
    sb.Append("},");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
```

I was wondering which one would be better from performance as well as maintenance point of view.

NOTE : Please consider that I've trimmed the code to post here original code is much larger than this, and I'm using MSSQL 2008 and .Net(C#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to get your data through SQL Server, create an object based on that data in C# and use JSON serializers for JSON. May be [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/). You  may face problems with maintaining your code with your current approaches.

Comment: +1 : This approach maintains the separation of layers in the application *(don't do formatting in the data layer if you can avoid it)*, and suggests a clear and maintainable way of managing that formatting.  In short, it's option 2, made neater.

Answer (score 1):

Get "normal" data from your SQL server, and use a stable library like [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to serialize it to json.

Answer (score 1):

Both are bad.

It's not the database's responsibility to give you the external format of your data. So the first one's a no.

In the second you're using string concatenation to build your JSON. That's fragile.

A good approach would be to load your data into objects and then serialize them to JSON using a JSON library.

```
DataTable dtable = GetDataFromDatabase();
var data = from row in dtable
           select new { Comment = row["Comment"],
                        Name = row["Name"] };

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String json = serializer.Serialize(data);
```

Comment: How can I Serialize a DataTable it was giving an error of cycling reference.